# TFS 2010 and connecting across two domains through a VPN tunnel

Tags: tfs

I'm getting the dreaded TF30063 error from TFS 2010 when I have users connecting to it from a remote location.
The exact error is

> TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/7.5

The setup is as follows:

TFS in DomainA and LocationA
UserA in DomainB and LocationB
VPN tunnel between both Locations
UserA has an account in DomainA and DomainB, DomainB credentials are stored in the windows credential manager for the TFS server so when Visual Studio starts it automatically connects to TFS without prompting for credentials.

The problem:

UserA can browse the source code no problem. But then run a get latest version on a folder where there is a significant amount of sub folders or code, about 1 minute into the download the error above appears and UserA no longer has the ability to browse the source code folders or run any get latest. The user needs restart VS to be able to browse code again.

We have exhausted the internet for solutions and have tried all of them except setting up Trust between the two domains. As anyone had the same issue before? About to pull out the little hair that I have left!

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239517/147211)

Answer (score 0):

Little late perhaps, but maybe this will help:

[Publishing visual studio’s Team foundation server through UAG](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/forefrontsecurity/archive/2010/01/05/publishing-visual-studio--team-foundation-server-through-uag.aspx)